# How do I improve the efficiency of the PyQt4 QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistwidget

I have the following code and am wondering if there is a way to make this more efficient. The setCurrentItem() and scrollToItem() functions seem to slow the process down considerable.  Also, I would like to see the items show up in the list as they are added instead of all at once after the loop has completed.  Any help or discussion would be greatly appreaciated.

```
import sys
from math import *
#from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import (Qt, SIGNAL, QSize)
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QDialog, QLabel, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem,     QPushButton, QScrollArea, QTextDocument, QVBoxLayout)
from time import localtime, strftime
import time

class LogDlg(QDialog):

  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(LogDlg, self).__init__(parent)
    self.resize(450, 380)

    self.log1 = QListWidget()
    self.log2 = QListWidget()
    lbl = QLabel()
    lbl_2 = QLabel()
    lbl.setText("Communications Log")
    lbl_2.setText("Command/Data Log")
    self.pushButton = QPushButton()
    self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QSize(110, 24))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

    self.pushbutton = QPushButton
    self.pushButton.setText("Start Log Loop")
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    layout.addWidget(lbl)
    layout.addWidget(self.log1)
    layout.addWidget(lbl_2)
    layout.addWidget(self.log2)
    self.setLayout(layout)
    self.setWindowTitle("Transaction Logs")
    self.connect(self.pushButton,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.logLoop) 
    self.time = time.time()

  def logLoop(self):
    for i in range(1000):
        print i
        self.addLog("This is a test","c",True)      

  def timeStamp(self):
    now = time.time()
    localtime = time.localtime(now)
    milliseconds = '%02d' % int((now - int(now)) * 100)
    val = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S.', localtime) + milliseconds
    return val

  def clearUi(self):
    self.log1.clear()
    self.log2.clear()

  def addLog(self, data, type="c", ts=False):
#        pass
    t = self.timeStamp()
    if ts == True:
        data = t + " " + data
    if type == "c":
        self.listItem1 = QListWidgetItem()
        self.listItem1.setText(data)
        self.log1.addItem(self.listItem1)
#        self.log1.scrollToItem(self.listItem1)
        self.log1.setCurrentItem(self.listItem1)


    elif type == "d":
        self.listItem2 = QListWidgetItem()
        self.listItem2.setText(data)
        self.log2.addItem(self.listItem2)
#        self.log2.scrollToItem(self.listItem2)
        self.log2.setCurrentItem(self.listItem2)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = LogDlg()
form.open()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue doesn't have anything to do with `.scrollToItem` or `.setCurrentItem`. The loop in `logLoop` method doesn't give any chance for the Qt event loop to update things. One way to solve it is, give the Qt a chance to update the GUI with `QApplication.processEvents()`. So if you modify the `logLoop` as following, you should see the items as they are added:

```
  def logLoop(self):
    for i in range(1000):
        print i
        self.addLog("This is a test","c",True)
        QApplication.processEvents()
```

This is useful to some degree. If the time between `processEvents` is small enough you'll get a responsive UI. But once things get more complicated and the time to complete tasks for each segment increases, you'll need to delegate that piece of code to a separate thread (`QThread`) in order to keep the GUI responsive.

One other issue is, things will get slower once you have a large number of items in the `QListWidget`. You may notice that adding the 25th item is faster than 925th item. That's because `QListWidget` (or `QTableWidget`/`QTreeWidget`) doesn't scale well. If you are going to have large number of items, model/view framework (`QListView`/`QTableView`/`QTreeView`) should be your choice.

Comment: Thank you very much. This info has helped me a lot, but I still see a huge difference in time if I have the .setCurrentItem command after each add. As a requirement for my application, I have to have the newest line at the bottom of the list and always show the newest line. My application adds a line every .3 seconds, so it adds up quickly. I'll start working on a QListView version to see what kind of advantage I get. Thanks again.

Comment: @Stephen: Sure, there'll be a difference if you use `.setCurrentItem` or not. It's not _free_ after all, it adds an overhead :). An item per `0.3s` is not that bad. It should be manageable. But scaling issue of `QListWidget` is still there. You can observe it. Add 500 items and measure the time required, then add 500 more. Second one would be slower.

Comment: Using the QTextBrowser and the QTextBrowser.append() gave me the best results for what I was trying to accomplish.